# how to add log.path and data.path to elastic.yaml for kuberenetes to deploy with operator

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

**
good day!

i try to deploy elastic with operator in Kubernetes with this code
**

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elastic-cluster
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  version: 7.16.3
  nodeSets:
  - name: data
    count: 1
    config:
      node.master: false
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: false
      xpack.ml.enabled: false
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
       containers:
          - name: elasticsearch
            env:
            #  - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            #    value: -Xms1g -Xmx1g
              - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
                value: "30"
            #resources:
            #  requests:
            #    memory: 1Gi
            #    cpu: 1
            #  limits:
            #    memory: 1Gi
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2G
```

**
but i dont know where in this file to mount the log.path and data.path and how to do it
any help?
**

*
italic
*